# Tools for initializing a database with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm looking for a way to initialize a database with a set of preliminary data. I've been looking around, but haven't seem to find anything that exactly matches what I'd like to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: What data storage option do you plan to use on App Engine?

Comment: I'm currently using NDB.

Answer (score 0):

The Datastore Administration allow to [copy data to another app](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/datastoreadmin#copying_entities_to_another_application). But if you need this tool for testing your app in local, as I suppose, you could write a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this programatically. Write a function that initializes your database and call it from inside a dedicated URL handler, e.g.

```
http://myapp.com/prepareDb
```

See [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Requiring_login_or_administrator_status) how to configure this URL so that only admins of the app have permission to access it.

An HTTP request coming from a user has 60 seconds to complete before it is aborted by app engine. If, for some reason, you need more than 60 seconds to prepare your database, do it from a cron job (which has 10 minutes to finish).